# Processing.js - Sleep, Wait, TimeOut, Pause, Delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, processing, processing.js

Is there a sleep() function for Processing.js? If not what would be a suitable alternative to add a delay in the draw() loop?

I am using JQuery with Processing - can I use a JQuery or Javascript function to cause a sleep type delay in the loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processing has a [delay()](http://processing.org/reference/delay_.html) function but unfortunately that is not implemented into Processing.js yet.

You can mix JS(JQuery,etc.) with Processing though.
[Processing 1.9.9](http://code.google.com/p/processing/downloads/list) has a Javascript mode now and there are examples for Processing/DOM integration, like [SelectionFlower](http://code.google.com/p/processing/source/browse/trunk/processing/javascript/examples/Environment/DocumentObjectModel/selectionFlower/selectionmonitor.js).
In the [sketch/pde file](http://code.google.com/p/processing/source/browse/trunk/processing/javascript/examples/Environment/DocumentObjectModel/selectionFlower/selectionFlower.pde) there is a method setup to be called form js:

```
// called from JavaScript
void setSelectionText ( String txt )
{
    selectedText = txt;
}
```

and in the js file, a timeout is set to make sure the sketch is initialized and can be accessed:

```
var mySketchInstance;

// called once the page has fully loaded
window.onload = function () {
    getSketchInstance();
}

// this is called (repeatedly) to find the sketch
function getSketchInstance() {
    var s = Processing.instances[0];
    if ( s == undefined ) {
        setTimeout(getSketchInstance, 200); // try again a bit later

    } else {
        mySketchInstance = s;
        monitorSelection();
    }
}
```

Then when the sketch instance is available, you can simply call a method/function on the sketch:

```
function monitorSelection () {
//bla bla
mySketchInstance.setSelectionText(txt);  // set the text in the sketch
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution.

```
void waitasec (int sec) {

   int minutes = minute();
   int seconds = second();
   int hour = hour();
   int starttime = (hour * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds;
   int finaltime = starttime + sec;

   while (starttime < finaltime) {

       minutes = minute();
       seconds = second();
       starttime = (hour * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A resource consuming solution:

```
int timer = 0;
void draw() {
 if (timer%50 == 0) {
  //some code here
 }
 timer = timer +1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

**.delay( duration [, queueName] )**

**Description:** Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

See the link http://api.jquery.com/delay/